# Rails, How to make it so only admin can add a drama and delete a drama

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I'm creating a rails app for korean dramas, and all of the dramas are created by seeding it into the database. I want to make an option as well so that an admin can add drama and delete them, not users. Would I need to add a user as an admin, set it to boolean somehow? Here is my seeds db :

```
dramas = [
    {name: "Goblin", genre: "Comedy, Romance, Fantasy, Melodrama, Supernatural"},
    {name: "Its Okay, thats Love", genre: "Friendship, Psychological, Comedy, Romance, Drama"},
    {name: "Its Okay to Not be Okay", genre: "Psychological, Comedy, Romance, Drama, Family"},
    {name: "Start-Up", genre: "Business, Comedy, Romance, Youth, Drama"},
    {name: "Secret", genre: "Romance, Drama, Melodrama"},
    {name: "Secret Garden", genre: "Comedy, Romance, Drama, Melodrama, Supernatural"},
    {name: "Flower of Evil", genre: "Thriller, Mystery, Psychological, Romance, Crime, Melodrama"},
    {name: "Strong Woman Do Bong Soon", genre: "Action, Thriller, Comedy, Romance, Drama, Supernatural"},
    {name: "W", genre: "Action, Suspense, Thriller, Comedy, Romance, Drama, Fantasy, Melodrama"},
    {name: "Pinocchio", genre: "Thriller, Mystery, Comedy, Romance, Melodrama"},
    {name: "Healer", genre: "Action, Thriller, Mystery, Comedy, Romance, Drama"},
    {name: "While You were Sleeping", genre: "Thriller, Mystery, Comedy, Romance, Drama, Fantasy"},
    {name: "The Smile has Left your Eye", genre: "Thriller, Mystery, Romance, Drama"},
    {name: "Kill me, Heal me", genre: "Psychological, Comedy, Romance, Drama"},
    {name: "I'm not a robot", genre: "Friendship, Comedy, Romance, Drama, Sci-Fi"},
    {name: "The Beauty inside", genre: "Comedy, Romance, Family, Melodrama, Supernatural"},
    {name: "Angel's last mission: Love", genre: "Comedy, Romance, Drama, Fantasy"},
    {name: "King: Eternal Monarch", genre:  "Mystery, Romance, Drama, Fantasy"},
    {name: "My Girlfriend is a Gumhiho", genre: "Comedy, Romance, Drama, Fantasy, Supernatural"},
    {name: "Tale of the Nine-Tailed", genre: "Action, Suspense, Thriller, Horror, Romance, Fantasy"},
    {name: "Weightlifting Fairy Kim Bok Joo", genre: "Friendship, Comedy, Romance, School, Youth, Sports"},
    {name: "Boys over Flowers", genre: "Friendship, Comedy, Romance, School, Youth, Drama"},
    {name: "What's Wrong with Secretary Kim", genre: "Friendship, Business, Comedy, Romance"},
    {name: "Cheese in the Trap", genre: "Friendship, Psychological, Romance, Life, Drama"},
    {name: "Dream High", genre: "Friendship, Music, Comedy, Romance, School, Drama"},
    {name: "Oh My Venus", genre: "Friendship, Comedy, Law, Romance, Life, Drama, Sports"}
 ]

dramas.each do |drama|
    Drama.create drama 
end
```

Here is my user model :

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews 
    has_many :dramas, :through => :reviews
    validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true 
    validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true 
    has_secure_password 
end
```

Here is my dramas model :

```
    class Drama < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews 
    has_many :users, :through => :reviews
    validates :name, uniqueness: true
    before_validation :make_title_case  
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
    

    def self.alphabetized
        all.order('name asc')
    end
    private

    def make_title_case
    self.name = self.name.titlecase
    end
end
```

Here is my dramas controller :

```
class DramasController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_by_drama, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
before_action :current_user, only: [:create, :update, :edit, :show, :destroy]
def index 
    @dramas = Drama.alphabetized
end 

def new    
    @drama = Drama.new 
end  


def show 
    session[:drama_id] = @drama.id
    @drama = Drama.find(session[:drama_id])
end 

def create 
    @drama = Drama.new(drama_params)
    if @drama.save 
        redirect_to dramas_path
    else 
        render :new 
    end 
end 

def update 
    @drama = Drama.update(drama_params)
    redirect_to dramas_path 
end 

def edit 
end 

def destroy 
    @drama.destroy
    redirect_to dramas_path 
end 

private 

def drama_params
    params.require(:drama).permit(
        :name,
        :genre,
        reviews_attributes: [
            :title,
            :rating,
            :content,
            :user_id,
            :drama_id
          ]
    )
end
```

end

And lastly, users controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new 
end 

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
        session[:user_id] = @user.id 
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else 
        @errors = @user.errors.full_messages
        render :new  
end
```

end

```
def show 
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @drama = Drama.find_by(params[:drama_id])
end 

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.delete
    redirect_to '/signup'
end 

private
def user_params 
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
end
```

end

Comment: I highly recommend use rubocop when you write some ruby code. It will be easier and more enjoyable to read: https://rubocop.org

Answer (score 1):

There is so many approaches to solve what you want.

I think you can define an admin role to your user model then add method to your user model to check is admin or not.

Add field role (a string) to your user model. and add a method admin?

```rb
    class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :reviews 
     has_many :dramas, :through => :reviews
     validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true 
     validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true 
     has_secure_password

     def admin?
       role == 'admin'
     end
    end
```

Then in your Drama controller you can validate

```rb
def create
   if current_user.admin?
    @drama = Drama.new(drama_params)
    if @drama.save 
        redirect_to dramas_path
    else 
        render :new 
    end 
   else
    # do something
   end
end
```

and the destroy method

```rb
def destroy
   if current_user.admin?
    @drama.destroy
    redirect_to dramas_path
   else
    # do something
   end
end
```

you can actually disable your edit page or new page in your view if it's not an admin. that is another approach.

you can use cancancan gem also to define the ability what can admin do and what can usual user do.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your business needs, boolean admin flag can work, but this is not flexible solution.

More complex thing is to use something like https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify with combination of authorization solution like https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan.

On later stage of your project, you will be able to easily introduce new roles and different layers of authorization.

Common practice is to have some CMS thing like https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin where all the management things will be separated from your public controller and keep them simple by decoupling management logic. In that case, e.g. you can have separate Admin model with it's own authentication and not to overload User model by roles system.

Specially I prefer separate Admin model and keep things simple because the User model is always heavy and holds lots of different business logic on later edges of a project.